# How do I get pixels per unit length after calling calibrateCamera?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm calibrating a camera using a grid of circles. The camera is in a fixed location above a table so I'm using a single image for calibration. (All the objects I’ll be working with will be flat and on the same table as my calibration image.) I'm putting the real-world locations of the circle centers into `objectPoints` and passing that to `calibrateCamera`.

Here is my calibration code (basically distilled down from the OpenCV `calibration.cpp` sample program to work for a single image):

```
int circlesPerRow = 56;
int circlesPerColumn = 32;
// The distance between circle centers is 4 cm
double centerToCenterDistance = 0.04;

Mat calibrationImage = imread(calibrationImageFileName, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

vector<Point2f> detectedCenters;
Size boardSize(circlesPerRow, circlesPerColumn);
bool found = findCirclesGrid(calibrationImage, boardSize, detectedCenters);
if (!found)
{
    return ERR_INVALID_BOARD;
}

// Put the detected centers in the imagePoints vector
vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints;
imagePoints.push_back(detectedCenters);

// Set the aspect ratio to 1
Mat cameraMatrix = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
double aspectRatio = 1.0;
cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 0) = 1.0;

Size imageSize(calibrationImage.size());

vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
Mat distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);

// Create a vector of the centers in user units
vector<vector<Point3f> > objectPoints(1);
for (int i = 0; i < circlesPerColumn; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < circlesPerRow; j++)
        objectPoints[0].push_back(Point3f(float(j*centerToCenterDistance), float(i*centerToCenterDistance), 0));

int flags = CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO | CALIB_FIX_K4 | CALIB_FIX_K5;
calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, flags);
```

After calling `calibrateCamera` how do I calculate the number of pixels per meter on the same plane as the calibration circles in an undistorted image?

Comment: it actually depends on the depth of the image. 1 m in a closer distance will be equivalent to more pixels. Also it depends how the 1 m is used, like a horizontal line? vertical? or maybe in depth ? An easy way to know, is to create 2 3D points (or more in case of area) and project them to the 2D plane using your calibration (projectPoints function in OpenCV) then you measure the distance between the 2 2D points and you get how many pixels you have.

Comment: @api55 You’re correct. I forgot to specify that everything I’m looking at is on the same plane as the calibration image. I’ll add that to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you are doing a calibration with only 1 image... it is recommended to use several images in different positions to get more accurate results, because you are calculating the intrisic parameters, if it was only the camera pose, PnP would be enough.

[calibrateCamera](http://camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction) will give you the intrinsics (camera matrix) parameters needed to project 3D points to the image plane of the camera. It will also give the Extrinsic parameters needed the origin to the camera origin (one per image given).

Once you do this calibration you can create a set of points, for example:

```
cv::Vec3f a(0., 0., 0.), b(1., 0., 0.);
```

Assuming that you are using meters in your world coordinate units, if not multiply accordingly :)

Now you have 2 options, the manual way which is apply the pin hole camera model formula to this two points, using as extrinsics the ones generated from your image that has the desired camera pose (in your case you only have one). Or you can use project points like:

```
// your last line
cv::calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, flags);
// prepare the points
std::vector<cv::Point3f> pointsToProject{cv::Vec3f{0., 0., 0.},cv::Vec3f{0., 1., 0.}};
std::vector<cv::Point2f> projectedPoints;
// invert the extrinsic matrix
cv::Mat rotMat;
cv::rodrigues(rvecs[0], rotMat);
cv::Mat transformation = cv::Mat::eye(4,4,CV_32F);
rotMat.setTo(transformation(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)));
transformation.at<float>(0,3) = tvecs[0][0];
transformation.at<float>(1,3) = tvecs[0][1];
transformation.at<float>(2,3) = tvecs[0][2];
transformation = transformation.inv();

// back rot and translation vectors
cv::Mat rvec, tvec(3,1,CV_32F);
cv::rodrigues(transformation(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)), rvec);
tvec.at<float>(0) = transformation.at<float>(0,3);
tvec.at<float>(1) =transformation.at<float>(1,3);
tvec.at<float>(2) =transformation.at<float>(2,3);

cv::projectPoints(pointsToProject, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, projectedPoints );
double amountOfPixelsPerMeter = cv::norm(projectedPoints[0]-projectedPoints[1]);
```

However this will give a meter distance before the extrinsics is applied, so even if it is in x axis, it may be different depending on the rotations.

I hope this helps, if not leave a comment. I wrote most of it out of my head, so it may have a typo or something.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After I thought about this some more, I realized that I skipped the next step after calibrating the camera of transforming the image so that the image plane is parallel to the camera plane. When I do that, I'm in charge of the size of the image so the pixels per length is whatever I want it to be. I calculate it by dividing the real world distance between two centers by the number of pixels between the centers in the undistorted, transformed image. I'm sorry my question wasn't thought out well enough.